# How do you add a panel overlapping the hero image (as foreground)

Tags: html, css, user-interface

I have tried giving the panel a z-index of 1000,
and positioning it as absolute, and the hero image as relative.
But the panel is  still not moving to the front.

`

```
<!--hero-->
      <section class="hero">
            <section class="container">
                <h1>TITLE</h1>
                subtitle lorem ipsum
                 <br><br>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><a href="sobre.php"><b>saiba mais<b></button> 
            </section>
      </section>        
<!--hero-->

<!-- painel de foreground----->
    <div class="overlay">
    <h3>about us something something<h3>
    </div>
<!-- painel de foreground---->`
```

CSS:

```
    `
.overlay{
width:60%;
position:absolute;
left:0;
z-index: 1000;
background-color:#fff;
border:1px solid #fff;
width:300px;
height:120px;
padding-left:30%;
}



.hero {
    width: 100%;
    background: url("../img/hero/2.png"); no-repeat center center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    display: table;
    position:relative;
    z-index:-1;
    }

    .hero .container {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 689px;
    }
    `
```

Like so:
https://cdn.elegantthemes.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/material-overlap-divi-contact-form.png

Comment: Can you post what you have tried ? Show us your actual code

Comment: As per your attached mock-up, why are you using `position` anyway you can play with `background` property and can easily achieve that.

Comment: Please can you [read this post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it) and create an [MCVE]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just made an demo.. You just have to give position relative to that element and move it with to or bottom with some z-index.Hope this will help.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  max-width: 80%: width:100%;
  margin: 0px auto;
}

.simpleText {
  width: 48%;
  margin: 20px 2% 20px 0;
  padding: 20px 0;
  text-align: left;
  float: left;
}


/* Positioned Element */

.panelPosition {
  width: 48%;
  margin: 20px 0% 20px 2%;
  padding: 10px 0;
  background: green;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: -80px;
  z-index: 2;
}

footer {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 100px 0;
  background: red;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <section>
    <div class="simpleText">
      <h3>Hello Demo !!</h3>

    </div>
    <div class="panelPosition"> Positioned Element</div>

  </section>
</div>

<footer>
  I am footer
</footer>
```

Comment: Thank you, that works! Just had to play with the height and margins.

Answer (score -3):

all you need is here: [www.w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_zindex) If you still need help, you need to show us what you did so far...

```
img {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: -1;
}
```